# Is it sufficient to prove $P(x) \geq a$ if we already know $P(x) > a$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, theorem-provers

Is it sufficient to prove $P(x) \ge (\text{or} \le) a$ if we already know $P(x) > (\text{or}  <)a$?

For example, to prove 
$$
\forall n \ge 1 , \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2} \le 2
$$

Suppose I have already proved 
$$
\forall n \ge 1 , \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2} < \frac{7}{4} - \frac{1}{n}
$$
Then, are we done? (Because $\frac{7}{4}-\frac{1}{n} < 2 \le 2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. If "greater than" is true, then "greater than or equal to" is true. Look at the truth table under **OR** here: https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-truth-tables-boolean-algebra-73b331dd9b94.

Comment: Opps! I just found that $\le$ means less that **or** equal to in English, so it is actually kind of a logic union.